# Github error: local repository cannot be resolved to branch?

Tags: git, github

I know this has been brought up before, but for some reason I keep getting this error when trying to do `git push origin random` to sync to Github. It was working fine before, and I suspect it has something to do with the fact that I accidentally denied keychain permissions on Mojave. The username and password queries (since it is a private repository) pop up, but after I enter my password, this error message occurs.

For reference, everything is spelled correctly. I am able to commit to my local branch without problems, and I see the `random` branch listed when I call `git branch`. `git status` also shows that I am working on the `random` branch.

Does anyone know how to fix this?